# Аналог mod_rewrite Апача для Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Я достаточно долго работал с Апачем и привык к тем возможностям, которые дает `mod_rewrite`. Есть ли в Nginx механизм преобразования URL, сопоставимый по возможностям с `mod_rewrite`?

Answer (score 2):

Да, Nginx имеет модуль для преобразования URL, не уступающий по функционалу `mod_rewrite`. Это [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule). Модуль позволяет менять URI на основе регулярных выражений, а также выбирать конфигурацию на основе переменных.